# When To Use A Particular Rails Environment for Testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, test-environments, rake-test

I am teaching myself Ruby On Rails with Michael Hartl's Book. When it uncovered the use of *seeds.rb* file, I tested within **Development Environment**, it *Failed*. When set to **Test Environment**, It *Succeeded*. Why? When will I need to change the environment again for successful tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `I tested within Development Environment, it Failed.`, you are not running automated tests. You ran the `rake db:seed` script against the development database. The same task can be run against the test environment with `rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test`. Again, this is not an automated test.

There are many reasons why `rake db:seed` run against the development environment failed in your case. The specific reason could be identified based on the error message.

`development` environment is one where you work on a day to day basis, adding/changing functionality by making code changes. By default, most scripts assume that you are working with `development` environment.

`test` environment is the environment against which the automated tests are run. In the case of rails tutorial, the automated tests are written in the files under `test` folder. When automated tests are run on a rails application - with `rake test` or some other way - the `test` environment is used to run these tests against. The `test` database gets cleaned up before running the tests to ensure the tests are run starting with a blank state.

Hope this clarifies.